# Coppersmith method of small integer solutions to multivariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, lattices

In http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-68339-9_14#page-7 is presented a method for finding small solutions to multivariate polynomials. (Although here he mentions that it "is not rigorous", several other papers have cited it and make use of it in practice.) Is there a function or convenient snippet for accomplishing this in Mathematica? Or if not, perhaps at least a reference for how to write this slightly more algorithmically?

Edit: In particular, I need this for the case of solving quadratics in two variables over large composite fields of unknown factorization, efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = PolynomialMod[Expand[(1 + x) (2 + y) (3 + xy) (2 + z) (4 + z)], 5]
```

> `3+3 x+xy+x xy+4 y+4 x y+3 xy y+3 x xy y+z+x z+2 xy z+2 x xy z+3 y z+3 x y z+xy y z+x xy y z+z^2+x z^2+2 xy z^2+2 x xy z^2+3 y z^2+3 x y z^2+xy y z^2+x xy y z^2`

```
FactorSquareFree[f, Modulus -> 5]
```

> `(1 + x) (3 + xy) (2 + y) (3 + z + z^2)`

As we can see this works. Not sure though that `Factor` uses the Coppersmith algorithm. Maybe one can use some of the functions employing the LLL scheme such as `FindIntegerNullVector`and `LatticeReduce` to implement it.

Comment: I'll try this out in the morning. It's important that I get reasonable efficiency for large coefficients and moduli. When I tried it with Solve it was definitely operating exponentially slowly.

Comment: Upon trying this -- `FactorSquareFree` requires that the `Modulus` be prime -- which kind of defeats the purpose of Coppersmith's algorithm. I agree that `LatticeReduce` will be necessary, but I'm not sure about building the matrix which I will reduce, or interpreting the results.